# scala com.datastax.driver.core.Row.getList usage

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax

I am struggling to get this code section to even compile:

The reason is I don't understand the `getList` parameters.

- Do I use scala classes or java classes for the second parameter?
- Also, I need `List[Int]` and `List[Double]` but `row.getList` returns
  `List[Any]`

  ```
  val rst:Try[ResultSet]=executeQuery(query)

  rst.isSuccess match {
    case true =>
      val rs:ResultSet=rst.get
      val rsList:mutable.Buffer[Row] = rs.all.asScala
      rsList.map { row =>
          val uuid=row.getString("uuid")
          val hc=row.getInt("hashcode")
          val indices:List[Int]=row.getList("indices",Int.getClass).asScala.toList
          val values:List[Double] = row.getList("values",Double.getClass).asScala.toList
          val label= row.getDouble ("label")
          val lp=new LabeledPoint(label, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.sparse(colCount, indices.toArray, values.toArray))
          (lp,lp.hashCode(),uuid)
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

OK, found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623346/how-to-retrieve-the-column-having-datatype-as-list-from-the-table-of-cassandra) so this is a duplicate

```
row.getList("indices", classOf[java.lang.Integer])
```